# Does multiple array of data affect performance? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent class which will pass props to a component class. These props are arrays `{door, window, carpet, curtain}` which I have imported from my `ProductInformation.js`

I seem to have solved my problem of my props not being defined. My logic was that I pass `<ProductSquare arrayId = {door}/>`  which would be the array name and  than the I would call `this.props.arrayId.map`  get error of undefined because `{door}` was obviously undefined.

I solved it by importing my data into my parent class and passing the  individual arrays itself to child component class.

**My question: Is this a efficient way to pass array data like this; is there a better logic?**

```js
import {door, window, carpet, curtain} from './ProductInformation2.js'


<Tabs forceRenderTabPanel>
            <TabList>
              <Tab>Front</Tab>
              <Tab>Rear</Tab>
              <Tab>Side</Tab>
            </TabList>
            <TabPanel>
            <div className = 'tabAreaSelected'>
                <ProductSquare arrayId = {curtain}/>
                <ProductSquare arrayId = {door}/>
                <ProductSquare arrayId = {window}/>
                <ProductSquare arrayId = {carpet}/>
                
            </div>
          
</Tabs>
```

Here is my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958535/map-over-a-array-based-on-prop-name-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment88914591_50958535)

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the options are; if they need an array, they need an array.

Comment: Yeah maybe i'm overthinking it. I was wondering if maybe you can place all your array data in the component and call it somehow inside the component by giving the component a keyword prop so it know which array to render instead of passing the whole array... if that makes sense.

Comment: Sure, you can pass whatever you want. All you're doing is passing around references--what they *reference* is up to you. Ideally components should only get the data they care about, but without more details, it's difficult to know what `<ProductSquare />` is or if it's getting only the data it cares about.